# Set Mutt's default save folder depending on the current folder

Tags: configuration, mutt

I would like to configure Mutt so that the default save folder changes depending on the current folder:

- When reading messages in the folder `=account1/Unsorted` or `=account1/Important` or any other sub-folder under `=account1/`, I'd like the default save folder (the one suggested when pressing <kbd>s</kbd> in the message index) to be `=account1/INBOX`.
- Likewise, for sub-folders of `=account2/`, I'd want the default save folder to be `=account2/INBOX`, etc.

How may I configure Mutt to do this?

- It appears `save-hook` would have been useful, if it had a way of matching against the folder name (I don't think it has).
- It appears `folder-hook` would have been useful, if it had a way of setting the save folder, but there is no save folder setting to set with the hook (there's `record`, but that's for outgoing messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Reportedly, the following two lines were used

```
folder-hook +account1 unhook save-hook
folder-hook +account1 save-hook . +account1/INBOX
```

repeated for each account.

---

Mutt, as you know, is configured by `.muttrc` file.
Look at `man muttrc`, the patterns at all others is there. I also do not see a folder pattern there but searching for `save` I found elsewhere

```
 Note that these expandos are supported in "save-hook", "fcc-hook" and "fcc-save-hook", too.
```

and above that

```
              %b     filename of the original message folder (think mailbox)
              %B     the list to which the letter was sent, or else the folder name (%b).
              %O     original  save  folder where mutt would formerly have stashed the message: list name or
                     recipient name if not sent to a list
```

Some of them could potentially be used, but  I do not see in `patterns` any way how to match against a fixed string and not against the message.

---

Use can make `procmail` (or whatever is messing with your incoming mail) to add a custom header line and use `-h` to test for it.

---

I think your solution will be using

```
     folder-hook [!]regexp command
              When  mutt enters a folder which matches regexp (or, when regexp is preceded by an exclamation
              mark, does not match regexp), the given command is executed.

              When several folder-hooks match a given mail folder, they are executed in the order  given  in
              the configuration file.
```

May be something like

```
folder-hook account1 unhook *
folder-hook account1 save-hook ~A   =account1/INBOX
or
folder-hook account1      save-hook  ".*"  =account1/INBOX
folder-hook ^=account1.*  save-hook  ........... ???


UPDATE: Reportedly, the following two lines were used as solution (and seem to work)
folder-hook +account1 unhook save-hook
folder-hook +account1 save-hook . +account1/INBOX
# repeated for each separate account
# Note: We know the documentation for folder-hook says "regexp", but using +account (for some given account) seems to work too for whatever reason
```

It is unlikely that the most recent `save-hook` take precedence, so
I added unhook (change it to `unhook save-hook` or whatever you test to work)

```
    unhook [ *  | hook-type ]
              This  command will remove all hooks of a given type, or all hooks when "*" is used as an argu-
              ment.  hook-type can be any of the -hook commands documented above.
```

---

---

The following info might be useful for other users who have simpler needs and somehow came to this page:

```
     save_address
              Type: boolean
              Default: no

              If set, mutt will take the sender's full address when choosing a default folder for  saving  a
              mail. If $save_name or $force_name is set too, the selection of the Fcc folder will be changed
              as well.

      save_name
              Type: boolean
              Default: no

              This  variable  controls how copies of outgoing messages are saved.  When set, a check is made
              to see if a mailbox specified by the recipient address exists (this is done by searching for a
              mailbox  in  the  $folder  directory with the username part of the recipient address).  If the
              mailbox exists, the outgoing message will be saved to that mailbox, otherwise the  message  is
              saved to the $record mailbox.

              Also see the $force_name variable.

An example:
set save_address=yes
```

---

---

Please tell me and others how you solved the problem.

Comment: Unhooking the save hook and setting a new one in two folder hooks seems to work.  So basically, `folder-hook +account unhook save-hook` followed by `folder-hook +account save-hook . +account/INBOX`.  As far as I can see right now, using only these two commands (repeated for each separate `account`) seems to do the trick.  Much thanks!  (NOTE: I _know_ the documentation for `folder-hook` says "regexp", but using `+account` (for some given `account`) seems to work too for whatever reason.)

Comment: I do not understand the plus in '+account', never mind. I warn about the dot after `save-hook`  -- you require *non-empty* From header or something, which depends on `default_hook` variable. I recomend `.*` if it works. `~A` would be even better (if it works)

Comment: The plus sign is the same as the equal sign to denote a folder under the main mail store. I wasn't thinking about it when I used `=` in the question, but I actually use `+` everywhere. It shouldn't matter. The lone dot should match as long as the message is non-empty. I usually have non-empty messages in my mailbox. Having an empty message is spectacular enough that I'd be quite ok with almost anything happening :-)

Comment: " as the message is non-empty " --- no, because documentation says regexp is matched as specified in `default_hook` variable. The sender and similar. You may argue that the sender is usually non-empty, which is true.

Comment: By "the message" I mean header+body, the whole thing, but I see what you mean by the `default_hook`.  This just means that matching on a dot will mean the message is from or to somebody (to someone from me, or to me from somebody), which sounds like a reasonable assumption to me.